# How can you condition based on if a Nuget package is installed, whether directly or transitively?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I want all projects in my solution to have a certain attribute if a certain Nuget package is pulled into it. I've tried in a `Directory.Build.targets`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Update="MyNugetPackage" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(PkgMyNugetPackage)' != ''">
  <MyProperty>true</MyProperty>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but it seems the generated property from `GeneratePathProperty` doesn't flow up to referencing projects, so this only sets `MyProperty` in projects which have a PackageReference directly in them, not also those that reference projects with a PackageReference.

Is there any way to do this or in general to pass information from a child project to a parent project? So projects can set variables visible to referencing projects, which could be accessed something like `$(ProjectReferences.MyChildProject.Property1)`?

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild doesn't have a first-class concept of parent and child projects. A project can invoke the running of another project and a project can 'reference' another project. But that doesn't create a relationship that has a representation. There is no syntax for addressing 'parent' or 'child' projects because there is no representation that the syntax would apply to.

A `ProjectReference` doesn't create a relationship between two projects. It indicates that a project needs the outputs of another project. A project that has one or more `ProjectReference` items will perform its compile step after the referenced projects have been built or have been verified to be up to date.

What version of MSBuild are you using? Recent versions of MSBuild have added enhancements that may help.

Comment: I'm using the .Net 6.0.300 SDK, so MSBuild 17.2